# insert with php code not working but phpmyadmin works fine

Tags: php, mysql

I have following tables and following is the query I have used all possible checks to solve this issue. The problem is the insert works with  phpMyAdmin but not with PHP. I tried everything but still have the same problem.

Here is my table code:

```
       CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cle` (
      `id` int(40) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       `title` varchar(444) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Article',
       `content` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
       `url` varchar(222) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
       `status` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
       `alt` varchar(400) DEFAULT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
       KEY `url` (`url`,`status`)
       ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Here is the insert code:

```
      INSERT INTO cle (content,url,alt) VALUES (' <br> <span name=KonaFilter style=\"width:100%;\"><center><font size=\"4\"><b>Rate? Part 1</b> by<b>  </b></font></center></span> <span> <br> <center>         <br><td><img src=\"http://a1.abc.com/a/spacer.gif\" height=\"0\" width=\"1\"></td></tr> <tr><td>Article Posted: 04/04/2005</td></tr> </table> </td> </tr> </table> <table cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"1\" width=\"100%\" border=0> <tr> <td><h1 style=\"color:02679D; font-size:16\"><b><span name=KonaFilter>Howe? Part 1</span></b></h1></td> <td align=\"right\">     <table border=0 cellpadding=4> <tr> <td valign=\"top\"> <img name=\"btn36\" src=\"http://a4.abc.com/a/js_feed_article.gif\" width=48 height=38 onclick=\"ClipBoard(input36);\" onmouseover=\"this.style.cursor = \'hand\';\"> <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"input36\" value=\'</td> <td valign=\"top\"> <a href=\"http://www.a.com/Email_Article.cfm?articleid=36\"><img src=\"http://a4.abc.com/a/email_me.gif\" width=38 height=33 border=0></a> </td> </tr>    </table> </td> </tr> <tr> <td colspan=2> </td> </tr> <tr><td><br>&nbsp;<br></td></tr> <tr>     <td valign=\"bottom\" colspan=2> <form name=\"formx\" action=\"/article_detail.cfm?articleid=36\" method=\"post\"> <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"flagged\" value=1> <input type=\"image\" src=\"http://a1.abc.com/a/categorize.gif\" alt=\"Is gory?\" onclick=\"flag();\"> </form> </td></tr> </tr> <tr><td colspan=2><img src=\"http://a1.abc.com/a/spacer.gif\" height=\"5\" width=\"1\"></td></tr> <tr><td colspan=2> <div align=left style=\"width:370; height:315;\">s we’ll sues. <br> Question 1:? Do on such as “read more here” or? <br> What bsite. “Read More Here” us ASP vendors, rates, why itrates. <br> <p><br<!-- --> <table cellspacing=1 cellpadding=\"1\" border=0 width=\"130\" bgcolor=\"5A5A5A\"> <tr> <td valign=\"middle\" align=\"right\" height=\"10\" style=\"background-repeat:no-repeat;\" bgcolor=\"ffffff\" background=\"http://a15.abc.com/a/catbox.gif\">&nbsp;<font face=\"arial\" style=\'font-size:12\'><b><font style=\'font-family:verdana; font-size:9\'>Rate This Article</font> <img onclick=\'closeWindow();\' src=\'/a/close.gif\'>&nbsp;</b></font></td> </tr> <tr><td bgcolor=\"dddcdd\"> <table cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\" width=\"100%\">       <tr> <td align=\"center\"> <table border=0> <form name=\"form2\" action=\"\" method=\"post\"> <tr><td colspan=5><input type=\"text\" name=\"xDesc\" value=\"\" style=\"border:0 px; font-size:10;background-color:dddcdd\" contenteditable=\"false\"></td>          </form> <tr> <td width=\"20%\">  </td> <td width=\"20%\"> <form name=\"rateform2\"            action=\"/feedback.cfm/36?articleid=36&title=2C1\" method=\"post\"> <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"rating\" value=2> <img src=\"http://a2.abc.com/a/empty_star.gif\" name=\"imagetwo\" alt=\"Minimal useful information.\" style=\"border:0px\" onclick=\"rate(2);\" onmouseover=\"starDesc(2);\" onmouseout=\"starDesc(0);emptyStar(2);\"> </form> </td> <td          width=\"20%\"> <form name=\"rateform3\" action=\"/f.cfm/36?articleid=36C1\" method=\"post\"> <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"rating\" value=3> <img src=\"http://a3.abc.c.gif\" name=\"imagethree\" alt=\"Decent and informative.\"  style=\"border:0px\" onclick=\"rate(3);\" onmouseover=\"starDesc(3);\" onmouseout=\"starDesc(0);emptyStar(3);\"> </form> </td> <td width=\"20%\"> <form name=\"rateform4\" action=\"/feedback.cfm/36?articleid=36&title=C1\" method=\"post\">          <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"rating\" value=4> <img src=\"http://a4.abc.com/a/emptyr.gif\" name=\"imagefour\" alt=\"Gre.\" style=\"border:0px\" onclick=\"rate(4);\" onmouseover=\"starDesc(4);\" onmouseout=\"starDesc(0);emptyStar(4);\"> </form> </td> <td width=\"20%\"> <form name=\"rateform5\" action=\"/fem/36?articleid=36&title=C1\" method=\"post\"> <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"rating\" value=5> <img src=\"http://a5.abc.com/a/empty_star.gif\" name=\"imagefive\" alt=\"A \'Must Read\'.\" style=\"border:0px\" onclick=\"rate(5);\" onmouseover=\"starDesc(5);\" onmouseout=\"starDesc(0);emptyStar(5);\"> </form> </td> </tr> </table> </td> </tr> </table>         </td> </tr> <tr><td bgcolor=\"5A5A5A\"><img src=\"http://a1.aer.gif\" height=\"8\" width=\"100%\"></td></tr> </table>  </div> <script type=\"text/javascript\"> //Enter \"frombottom\" or \"fromtop\" var verticalpos=\"frombottom\" function JSFX_FloatTopDiv() {    var tmpcookie = new Date();    chkcookie = (tmpcookie.getTime() + \'\');    document.cookie = \"chkcookie=\" + chkcookie + \"; path=/\"; if (document.cookie.indexOf(chkcookie,0) < 0) { divStayTopLeft.style.left=-1000;       }     else { starDesc(0); var startX = 0, startY = 100; var ns = (navigator.appName.indexOf(\"Netscape\") != -1); var d = document; function ml(id) { var el=d.getElementById?d.getElementById(id):d.all?d.all[id]:d.layers[id]; if(d.layers)el.style=el; el.sP=function(x,y){this.style.left=x;this.style.top=y;}; el.x = startX; if (verticalpos==\"fromtop\") el.y = startY; else{ el.y = ns ? page
              <p> </td> </tr> <tr><td align=\"center\" > <p>&nbsp;<p> <font size=3 color=990000>Doe?  Have a Comment?  POST IT!</font><p> <table cellspacing=1 cellpadding=\"4\" border=0 width=\"100%\" bgcolor=\"4D4D4D\" align=\"center\"> <tr> <td align=\"right\" height=\"23\" style=\"background-repeat:no-repeat;\" bgcolor=\"ffffff\" background=\"\">&nbsp;<font face=\"arial\" style=\'font-size:12\'><b>Re</b></font>&nbsp;    </td> </tr> <tr><td  bgcolor=\"dddddd\"> <form action=\"/post_.cfm\" method=\"post\">       <table width=\"100%\" cellpadding=3 border=0 cellspacing=1> </table> <table width=\"100%\" cellpadding=5 border=0> <tr><td colspan=2><font size=2><strong>Sue.</strong></font></td></tr> <tr> <td colspan=2 align=\"center\">Make this comment <input type=radio  selected name=PublicPrivate value=\"Public\" label=\"Public\"> <label for=\"Public\">Public</label> or <input type=radio  name=PublicPrivate value=\"Private\" label=\"Private\"> <label for=\"Private\">Private</label> to th:</td> </tr> <tr> <td align=\"right\">Name:</td> <td>     <input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" value=\"\" size=50> </td> </tr> <tr> <td align=\"right\" valign=\"top\">Email:</td> <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"Emss\" value=\"\" size=50><br>   <font size=1 color=\"ff0000\">*Youy.</font></td> </tr> <tr> <td align=\"right\" valign=\"top\">Comments:</td> <td><font size=1 color=\"ff0000\">*Yongly.</font><br>     <textarea cols=45 rows=10 name=\"Comments\"></textarea></td> </tr> <tr> <td>&nbsp;</td>       <td><img src=\"http://a6.abc.com/f.jpg\"></td> </tr> <tr> <td align=\"right\" valign=\"top\">Pge:</td> <td align=\"left\"><input type=\"text\" maxlength=6 name=\"ImageCode\" value=\"\" size=10></td> </tr> <tr> <td colspan=2 align=\"center\">      <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"ArticleID\" value=\"36\"> <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"x\" value=\"gwSIMR\"> <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"Author
       ID\" value=\"\"> <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"ReturnTo\" value=\"/article_detail.cfm?articleid=36\"> <input type=\"Submit\" value=\"Sut\" name=\"PostComment\"> </td> </tr> </table> </form> </td>         </tr> <tr><td  bgcolor=\"4D4D4D\"><img src=\"http://a1.abc.com/er.gif\" height=\"8\" width=\"100%\"></td></tr> </table>  </td></tr> </table> </span>                            <br>','http://www.a.com/article_detail.cfm?articleid=36','-')
```

Here is a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02327/1).

Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: Then paste your PHP Code...and btw you can create PHP code for qny through phpmyAdmin.

Comment: What error do you get? Note that for every class/method that handles database queries (`mysql_*`, `mysqli_*`, `PDO`, e.g.) there is a method available that lets you print the sql error

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: your sqlfiddle works when you put your insert statement from the right unter the create statement on the left

Comment: It works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8bf80/1 (I just copied your `INSERT` into the left-hand panel, which is how SQLFiddle works).

Comment: @SalmanA  its not giving any error i have used mysql error() but no error at all but i cant see any entry in mysql

Comment: Your DB query it's OK http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cce79/1 your issue should be in PHP, show us some PHP code

Comment: @jcho360 i have used mysql_real_escape_string for all variables of insert

Comment: @halfer who is giving negative vote i have checked few days then only i have posted here .i dont know why people are here in hurry to put negative vote.if you think its silly question then solve it in 10 seconds and give whatever negative vote u want

Comment: I don't know who has given you a negative vote. It's not me, though it's tempting - the question does still need some work. There's two things wrong with it: (a) a _huge_ blob of SQL has been dumped into it, which requires substantial horizontal scrolling to check through, and (b) _still_ there's no PHP in it - @jcho360 asked for that already (c) this has been fixed, but the question was written entirely in lower case. Questions don't have to be works of art, but we do like a bit of effort here. So, in summary, it's not a silly question, it just needs a bit of extra work!

Comment: @halfer the problem has nothing to do with his SQL CODE,so we can't solve this problem with his actual description of the problem.

Comment: @jcho360: yes, indeed. I agree!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to escape things twice if you throw them in literal from PHP to MySQL. The first backslash will be interpreted by PHP, NOT by MySQL.

If you have a function called as follows (for example):

```
function_called("this\' quote");
```

The function will actually receive "this' quote", not the backslashed version.

To go around this, two solutions:

1. Rely on parametrization of queries provided by PDO or MySQLi (safer as well in the long run)
2. Double-escape stuff. This\' quote then becomes `This\\\' quote`. On first pass, \ is interpreted as \, \' turns into '. On second pass (MySQL), what remains is \'.

Comment: @sebastein-renauld  i am also thinking that problem is ' somewhere but already i have used mysql_real_escape_string to replace all such but still i can see that few are balance as i have taken this insert output from browser sohow do i do that so that i can replace all such '

Answer (score 0):

i think your insert query in wrong

you can use `name=\"KonaFilter\"` instead of `name=KonaFilter`

Answer (score 0):

i think problem is at this line - 
"s we’ll sues. 
 Question 1:?"
try to replace this line to 
"s we\’ll sues. 
 Question 1:?"

Comment: i am also thinking that problem is ' somewhere but already i have used mysql_real_escape_string to replace all such but still i can see that few are balance as i have taken this insert output from browser sohow do i do that so that i can replace all such '

Comment: can you show your error? can you wrap this method in try catch and get error message?

Comment: there is no error that is the problem otherwise i would have figured out. is there an yhthing which is stopping more than 8000 characters to enter in sql